# Questions for uploading photos into album

Tags: facebook, photo

we have developed an application with which we can generate a new album and than upload many photos into it. The generated album is then shown at the page profile.

Now we have the problem, that for some users which liked our page nearly each uploaded photo generates a single post and so the user gets for each photo a notification. So we dont know why this happens..

Is it maybe possible do deactivate the automatic posting of the album, when photos are uploaded into it? And to publish the album only when all photos are uploaded?

Comment: You can use parameter `no_story` to suppress feed stories for uploaded photos, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos

Comment: And how can i than publish the created album to the page over the api?